# Update options after initialization in owl carousel 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel-2

I am trying to update/re-initialize owl carousel 2 options. But not able to succeed. Below is the code

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    nav: true
});

// update/re-initialize options
if(condition){ 
    // update owl carousel option - loop: false
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `owl.stop()` for this, not sure if you can set options directly without having to recreate it.